# Communication between VLANs

Tags: switch, vlan

We have got a 16 port switch and is divided in 2 VLANS of 8 ports each:

```
VLAN1 uses port 1-8   with network 192.168.10.0/24
VLAN2 uses port 9-16  with network 192.168.20.0/24
```

Computer A is connected on VLAN1 port 1 with an IP of 192.168.10.5.

During a test on computer A I manually changed the IP from 192.168.10.5 to 192.168.20.5.  I did not change the physical port which is/was in VLAN **1**

However after doing this computer A was able to communicate with the computers on VLAN **2** (the 192.168.20.0/24 network).

Do you see this normal? It seems strange to me...

Comment: "and I put an IP of network 2"? It is unclear what you're asking, edit your question. E.g. give example IP addresses.

Comment: It depends how the rest of the network is configured. The switch shouldn't permit any traffic between VLANs unless specifically configured to do so, but other devices might, or the switch might be configured to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. lets say we've got a 16 port switch and is divided in 2 VLANS of 8 ports each (VLAN1 uses from port 1-8 and VLAN2 uses 9-16). VLAN1 has a network of 192.168.10.0/24, VLAN2 has 192.168.20.0/24.
Computer A is connected on VLAN1 port 1 with an IP of 192.168.10.5. During a test on computer A I changed manually the IP from 192.168.10.5 to 192.168.20.5, and doing this computer A was able to communicate with the computers on VLAN2 so the 192.168.20.0/24 network. Do you see this normal? It seems strange to me...

Comment: @Dave: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. Please see [the Help Center](http://superuser.com/faq#deletion) for more information why some posts are removed. If you're the "david" that asked the question, please respond to comments from the computer you asked the question from (or register on the site).

Comment: @david: I edited your post to include the information from the comment. I also changed the layout. Feel free to revert it if you do not like the new result. (However I think it is much easier to underdstand).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: This is not how VLANs are supposed to behave.
Sounds like your switch is not working correctly, has a funny port numbering, or is not configured as you have stated.

The behavior that you are describing would work this way on a single vlan.

Decent doc showing vlans from Cisco: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/25ew/configuration/guide/conf/vlans.html